# Displaying multiple results based on similarity Python

Tags: python, database, similarity

I would like to know if anyone could help me with this problem. Im a beginner at Python, and im trying to create a program. The problem is that i want to search for a person in a stats database, and then get the result of the 5 most similar players based on stats. Now i only get one name, and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the code that i have used, but it only displays 1 player, instead of the 5 players that are most similar.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

def compare_players(player_name, data):
    player = data[data['Player'] == player_name]
    player_stats = player.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
    player_stats = (player_stats - player_stats.mean()) / player_stats.std()
    
    data_stats = data.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])
    data_stats = (data_stats - data_stats.mean()) / data_stats.std()
    
    similarity = data_stats.dot(player_stats.T)
    top_5 = data.iloc[similarity.iloc[0,:].sort_values(ascending=False).index[:5]]
    return top_5

def run_search(folder_path, player_name, data):
    result = compare_players(player_name, data)
    for i, row in result[['Player', 'Team', 'Age']].iterrows():
        tree.insert("", "end", values=(row['Player'], row['Team'], row['Age']))

def on_search():
    player_name = entry.get()
    run_search(folder_path, player_name, data)


def load_data():
    global data
    data = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
            temp_data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
            data = pd.concat([data, temp_data], axis=0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = *Here i put the folder which contains many excel files*,
                                      title = "Select folder")

load_data()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Player Comparison")
root.geometry("600x400")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Enter player name:")
entry = tk.Entry(root)
search_button = tk.Button(root, text="Search", command=on_search)

label.pack()
entry.pack()
search_button.pack()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("Player", "Team", "Age"), show="headings")
tree.heading("Player", text="Player Name")
tree.heading("Team", text="Team")
tree.heading("Age", text="Age")
tree.pack(side="left", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

The code is most likely all over the place, but i try :D
Thanks for all answers in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "fuzzyWuzzy" library if you want to get similar outputs.

> from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

```
x = your element
y = similar element
if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x, y) > 70:
// do this
else:
// do this
```

70 means 70% similarity.